# User/Visitor tracking tool

Tags: apache-2.4, logging, ubuntu-18.04

Hello I'm looking for an user tracking tool/service for our apache 2.4 webserver on ubuntu. Goal is to track our users accross our page (all visited url's, exits, requests, redirects, errors and so on).

All this information are allready stored in the apache access.log, error.log. Now I'm searching for a tool/service that take these log-files, analyze the data and put this data in some optical design where I can easily access and filter the data.

Is there any service/tools available for my approach. Can be free/opensource but also paid.

Answer (score 1):

There are some tools that could help you:

- [Loggy](https://www.loggly.com/)
- [Apache Logs Viewer](https://www.apacheviewer.com/)
- [GoAccess](https://goaccess.io/)

Comment: I will take a look. Thank you so far.